# Handling special characters with lucene

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, special-characters

i haven't found the answer to my problem so I decided to write my question to get some help.

I use lucene to index the objects in computer memory(they exist only in my java code). While processing the code I index (using `WhitespaceAnalyzer`) the field with value `objA/4`.

My problem starts when I want to find it after the indexation (also using `WhitespaceAnalyzer`).

When i create a query `obj*` , I find all objects that start with obj - if i create a query `objA/4` I also can find this object.

However i don't know how to find all objects starting with `objA/` , when I create a query `objA/*` lucene is changing it to `obja/*` and finds nothing.

I've checked and "/" is not a special character so i dont need any "\" preceding it.

So my question is how to ask to get all objects that starts with `objA/` (for example - `objA/0`, `objA/1`, `objA/2`, `objA/3`)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `QueryParser.escape(String)` to escape everything correctly?

Answer (score -1):

The code i'm using:

```
String node = "objA/*";   

 Query node_query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(node, "nodeName", new WhitespaceAnalyzer());

 BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();  

 bq.add(node_query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

 System.out.println("We're asking for - " + bq);  

 IndexSearcher looker = new IndexSearcher(rep_index);

 Hits hits = looker.search(bq);
```